# stackoverflow.com serves desktop version to Fennec and Firefox OS

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

(I'm just creating this as a question so that it doesn't get lost.)

According to [Bug 828408](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=828408) stackoverflow.com serves a desktop site to Firefox OS (Boot to Gecko or B2G for short), when it should be serving the mobile site instead.

(I don't have enough reputation to tag this with a b2g tag.)

Comment: When are these guys going to learn to stick mobile in the user agent string?

Comment: when are we going to stop building separate sites for the false dichotomy of Small Touchscreen and Big Monitor With Keyboard?

Comment: @NickCraver Hmm, according to the Gecko user agent string reference, they do... I don't actually have a B2G device myself though.

Comment: @NickCraver See also this blog post: http://lawrencemandel.com/2013/03/01/help-wanted-firefox-os-ua-detection/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should have been fixed in a recent build.

Historically we've had a lot (and I do mean a lot) of trouble with conflicting mobile user agent strings.  Mostly full on tablets being difficult to distinguish from phones, which is really dumb since the UI you want on a 10" screen is rather different from a 4" one.

It's getting better, but I'm sure we've still got tons of edge cases as it's inherently pretty hacky to detect mobile agents.

Comment: Now VERIFIED FIXED in Bugzilla.